# Hashable subclasses of mutable classes in Python

Tags: python, inheritance, design-patterns, subclass

I want to build a subclass of a class which is basically a wrapper around a list/dictionary, and I want to use instances of this class as keys. In order to have easy access to the list/dictionary methods, I figured I can just subclass them, but then I lose hashability.

I understand that this is incompatible with the `__eq__` of the mutable classes (and I don't need it), so I came up with the following solution.

```
class Foo(list):
    __hash__ = object.__hash__
    __eq__ = object.__eq__
```

Though I doubt this will come up in my specific applications, I guess this might cause problems if another class (with its own `__hash__`) would appear between `Foo` and `list` in the MRO of a subclass.

1. Is there a more Pythonic way of doing this? I could just add a list/dictionary as an attribute and then simply use the attribute (which would make code elsewhere more cumbersome) or the list/dictionary methods I need (but that'd be much more messy if I need more than a couple of methods).
2. Is there some pattern/recipe that would allow me to do this sort of thing in a cooperative setting (in other words, how should I change the code if I do in fact anticipate another class between `Foo` and `list` in MRO)?

Comment: Instead I would wrap the dict class, and overwrite the set / get function to take lists and handle them in a predefined way

Comment: @FloLie: Yes, I thought about that, but it seems like a lot of code to write if I should want to have more methods, and I probably would, like `__iter__`, `__len__` etc.

Comment: You can pretty trivially write wrapper classes (using composition) if you implement `__getattr__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: What do you have in mind? I can see how `__getitem__`+`__setitem__` could be used (but then you still have lots of other methods...), but how would `__getattr__` help?

Answer (score 1):

I decided a provide an answer based on my comment, with a lot if `IFs`

As stated, I would rather change the implementation of the dict, to take a `list` as a key. This however does come with problems, that as others mentioned, is the reason why `lists` SHOULDN'T be keys.

A little explanation:

When looking at a mutable variable, it comes with two properties, that it can be compared by:

1. Its `identity`
2. Its `content`

**Identity**
When a variable is created such as `a=[1,2,3]` it is allocated a memory position which can be called with `id(a)`. This id identifies `a` even after `a` is modified. However with a second variable `b=[1,2,3]` when comparing `ids` we get `id(a) == id(b) = False`

**Content**
We can also look at the content of a variable in a very simple way by converting it to a String, so with above example `str(a) == str(b) = True`. However if we do

```
a = [1,2,3]
str_a = str(a)
a.append(4)
str_new_a = str(a)
```

we get `str_a == str_new_a = False`, which is problematic in the case of application as a key in a dict, because at the moment of saving the value, we take a 'snapshot' of `a` and later if we lookup by `a` after it changed, it wont match.

Therefore you will have to decide, if in your case *content* or **identity** is the relevant lookup criterion.

An example implementation with **hashableKey1** as an ID match and **hashableKey2** as a content mach is provided below.

```
from collections import Hashable

class CoolDict(dict):
    hashableKeyType = 1
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        print(name, value)
        if isinstance(name, Hashable):
            super().__setitem__(name, value)
        else:
            super(CoolDict, self).__setitem__(self.hashableKey(name), value)
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        if isinstance(name, Hashable):
            return super().__getitem__(name)     
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(self.hashableKey(name))   
    
    def hashableKey(self, name):
        if self.hashableKeyType == 1:
            return self.hashableKey1(name)
        elif self.hashableKeyType == 2:
            return self.hashableKey2(name)
    def hashableKey1(self, name):
        return id(name)
            
    def hashableKey2(self, name):
        return str(name)
    
coolDict  = CoolDict()

### hashableKey1:

#Working
key = [1,2,3]
coolDict[key] = 123
print(coolDict[key])

#Not Working
coolDict[[2,3,4]] = 234
print(coolDict[[2,3,4]])

### hashableKey2:
coolDict.hashableKeyType = 2

#Working
coolDict[[2,3,4]] = 234
print(coolDict[[2,3,4]])


#Not Working
key = [1,2,3]
coolDict[key] = 123
key.append(4)
print(key)
print(coolDict[key])
```

Comment: This is an interesting idea, I think I've misunderstood your comment somewhat. I'm not sure about the second method, though, for just the reasons you mentioned. (I think I've seen similar implementation somewhere on SO, with the same caveats.) Why do you think this solution is better than mine? (Also, three ifs is not a lot IMHO, especially if they're in separate methods and not nested. :) )

Comment: It may be just my thinking process. If I can change the behavior of a container handling items, I dont have to change the behavior of an item to be handled by an unrelated third, does that make sense? Your problem is not the list, that works fine, what doesnt work is the dict, because it 'doesn't' eat what you feed it. With ```ifs``` i didn't mean code ifs, but that either of both ways come with a lot of limitations and are risky in my oppinion, because sometimes you change identity by mistake (e.g. copying, subsetting, etc.) also when it comes to nested items you need to think if that impacts

Comment: I see. Well, my point is, I want a class which, while *functionally* is a list/dictionary wrapper with some extra fluff, *abstractly* represents a concrete object (e.g. a deck of cards, or an entity in an ECS) for which identity makes more sense than a bare list/dictionary/set/other mutable class. The main point is not being able to put lists/dicts in a container, but rather, having a class with (almost) all the list/dict functionality, which can also be put in a container.